Conditional Returns vs Multiplication in Rust
I have two functions the first one is a multiplication:
where a is a random number and b is 0.0 or 1.0:
pub fn multiplication(a: f64, b: f64) -> f64 {
    a * b
}

The other one is a conditional return based on b
pub fn branching(a: f64, b: bool) -> f64 {
    if b {
        a
    } else {
        0.0
    }
}

Initially I though that the branching function should be faster than the multiplication.
I wrote a benchmark to check if my guess was true and to my surprise it was not the case, both functions take almost the same time:
#![feature(test)]

extern crate test;

pub fn multiplication(a: f64, b: f64) -> f64 {
    a * b
}

pub fn branching(a: f64, b: bool) -> f64 {
    if b {
        a
    } else {
        0.0
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

    use super::*;
    use rand::{self, Rng};
    use test::Bencher;

    #[bench]
    fn bench_multiplication_by_0_1(b: &mut Bencher) {

        let size = 10000;
        let mut values = vec![0.0; size];
        let mut bools = vec![0.0; size];

        values
            .iter_mut()
            .for_each(|x| *x = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0.0..100.0));

        bools
            .iter_mut()
            .for_each(|x| *x = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0.0..1.0));

        b.iter(|| {
            for i in 0..size {
                multiplication(values[i], bools[i]);
            }
        });
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_branching(b: &mut Bencher) {

        let size = 10000;
        let mut values = vec![0.0; size];
        let mut bools = vec![true; size];

        values
            .iter_mut()
            .for_each(|x| *x = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0.0..100.0));

        bools
            .iter_mut()
            .for_each(|x| *x = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..2) == 1);

        b.iter(|| {
            for i in 0..size {
                branching(values[i], bools[i]);
            }
        });
    }
}


And I got this results
running 2 tests
test tests::bench_branching             ... bench:       3,228.86 ns/iter (+/- 81.78)
test tests::bench_multiplication_by_0_1 ... bench:       3,128.20 ns/iter (+/- 163.76)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 2 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 7.46s

I use vectors to try to avoid compiler optimizations and caching.
Did I do something wrong? Or in Rust is totally normal that the multiplication takes the same time as the conditional return?
EDIT: I made what @prog-fh suggested and added black_box to the result and to each input

    #[bench]
    fn bench_branching(b: &mut Bencher) {
        //let a a vector of randon f64 numbers generated by rand crate

        let size = 10000;
        let mut values = vec![0.0; size];
        let mut bools = vec![true; size];

        values
            .iter_mut()
            .for_each(|x| *x = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0.0..100.0));

        bools
            .iter_mut()
            .for_each(|x| *x = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..2) == 1);

        b.iter(|| {
            for i in 0..size {
                black_box(branching(black_box(values[i]), black_box(bools[i])));
            }
        });
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_multiplication_by_0_1(b: &mut Bencher) {
        //let a a vector of randon f64 numbers generated by rand crate

        let size = 10000;
        let mut values = vec![0.0; size];
        let mut bools = vec![0.0; size];

        values
            .iter_mut()
            .for_each(|x| *x = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0.0..100.0));

        bools
            .iter_mut()
            .for_each(|x| *x = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0.0..1.0));

        b.iter(|| {
            for i in 0..size {
                black_box(multiplication(black_box(values[i]), black_box(bools[i])));
            }
        });
    }

And I got this:
running 2 tests
test tests::bench_branching             ... bench:      15,748.84 ns/iter (+/- 1,057.69)
test tests::bench_multiplication_by_0_1 ... bench:       8,353.18 ns/iter (+/- 181.29)

Did I do something wrong?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79067601/unexpected-low-latency-when-casting/79067911#comment139416517_79067601

This is a totally different question.

I linked to my own comment on that question, which applies verbatim, both the potential problem (your loop can be optimized to nothing because you don’t use the return value) and the solution.

@Facuellarg but the comment still holds. Use black_box on parameters and result when benchmarking a function.

Do you mean to use black_box with the results? because I used vectors generated randomly to avoid those kinds of optimizations.

Regarding performance of the two function independently of a possibly biased benchmark, 64-bit multiplications are quite expensive but this can change a lot from one CPU to another. Branches can be very cheap if they can be fully predicted. Random branching is not predictable so it can be pretty expensive (more than 64-bit multiplications). That being said, this code can be optimized with branch-less instructions and more specifically SIMD blend which are very very fast. You are mainly measuring compiler optimizations and CPU details here.

You generated inputs randomly, but you aren’t using the outputs. You can return an output-dependent value from the b.iter(|| …) closure.

@Facuellarg yes, use black_box on the result. In general, I blindly use black_box when passing parameters too, in order to be certain the compiler won't find a way to predict something instead of generating the computation (constant propagation...). OK, here, with random generated values this is very unlikely. But without using the result to do something useful, we are almost certain that the compiler will elude entirely a pure function call (without side effect). This is where black_box helps, on the result. Something like black_box(fnct(black_box(p1), black_box(p2)).

I edited the bench as @prog-fh suggested and I got results that were not the ones that I expected. This is normal? Could be the branching more expensive than the multiplication?

How much does a mispredicted conditional branch cost? says 15-ish cycles. Looking up cycles for a 64-bit FMUL says 7-ish but can be amortized to 2-ish if the CPU can pipeline (which it should here). So yeah, those number comparisons look roughly correct.

@kmdreko: What CPU were you looking at where fmul wasn't fully pipelined?  Typical AArch64 CPUs can do at least one scalar fmul per clock cycle, typically more.  If you're talking about x86-64, the relevant instruction is mulsd not legacy x87 fmul. (https://godbolt.org/z/dcM1qn8aK); all recent mainstream x86 CPUs have 2/clock mulsd (0.5 cycle reciprocal-throughput), and even for 80-bit x87 fmul have 1/clock throughput.

@Facuellarg: Did you compile with full optimization enabled?  I'd have hoped this would auto-vectorize to branchless code either way, although for x86-64 maybe only worth doing with SSE4.1 for pmovzxbq xmm1, [rdi] loads to widen from 2 bools to 2 u64s.  (Or unroll with SSSE3 pshufb to do 16 bytes of bool compares with pcmpeqb and expand different pairs of bools to 64-bit for andps to mask values to 0 or leave them unchanged.)  But black_box on each separate scalar might be defeating that, forcing each value to exist in a register by itself, not as part of a SIMD vector.

I tried to look at the asm on https://godbolt.org/z/9E3MT9zqP , but the only way I could see anything was "link to binary", and then the resulting x86-64 binary contained no mulsd (scalar double) or mulpd (packed double) instructions.  And minimal use of XMM registers at all, no movsd loads either.  I don't know Rust very well, and "reveal linked code" on the source for the loop body doesn't scroll the asm window anywhere, only for the close brace of the for loop, but the asm there isn't a loop, it ends with call *%r15 (indirect call through a function pointer)

What hardware did you test on?

@PeterCordes ```Architecture:             x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):         32-bit, 64-bit
Address sizes:          39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
Byte Order:             Little Endian
CPU(s):                   20
On-line CPU(s) list:    0-19
Vendor ID:                GenuineIntel
Model name:             13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13700H
CPU family:           6
Model:                186
Thread(s) per core:   2
Core(s) per socket:   14
Socket(s):            1
Stepping:             2

